# Roboto font doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

I'm working on a blog design and the main font is Roboto, it's from Google fonts site.

The problem is that it's doesn't rendered correctly in Firefox, instead of using Roboto font, Firefox use Tahoma.

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: Roboto-Regular;
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: Roboto-Bold;
}
```

It works well in Chrome and Safari.

Thanks,

Comment: That CSS is not how you declare a font-face or specify font-family on elements. What is it supposed to be?

Comment: If you embed the font correctly, Firefox will display it correctly.

Comment: it depends on how you're using the Roboto font. There is additional code you need in order to reference the Robot-Regular font...and if you're using the `.eot` version of the file, it won't work in FF.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara For example I've a <h1> tag and the font is applied to it. It works well in Chrome and Safar, but in FireFox it renders Tahoma

Comment: The code you posted shouldn't do anything. It might even break the code from the Google Fonts stylesheet.

Comment: I'm using Firefox Developer Edition (73.0b8). I have the same problem as yours. but I think this problem is local. May be wrong settings, corrupt file etc.

Comment: that's my Google Hangouts chat list https://ibb.co/q01mTmQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a quick page which shows 3 fonts, Roboto, Tahoma and the default:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
    <body>
    <p class="roboto">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
    <p class="tahoma">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
    <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bptvC

On firefox it shows Roboto.

Answer (score 3):

To use Roboto in regular and bold versions, use this to include the style sheet in the page:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then you use the font family name `Roboto` and set the weight using the `font-weight` style.

You can set them like this, and always use a fallback font:

```
font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;

font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
```

Instead of the font weight names `normal` and `bold` you can also use the specific weight numbers `400` and `700`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Roboto Condensed font is broken in Firefox in Hungarian language.
In Chrome it works perfectly.

I tried the font using a Hungarian language test case 'árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép'.
This string contains all special characters in the Hungarian language.

The broken characters are 'ű' and 'ő'.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,regular,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
    <body>
    <p class="roboto">ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP<br>árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép</p>
    <p>ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP<br>árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the applied CSS:

```
.roboto {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```